# Dynamic site with client side scripting

Tags: scripting, client-server, html, client-side

In the case that someone (e.g. me) wants to create a dynamic web site (possibly with admin panel) at a specific organization but he cannot have a server-side scripting language, is there any recommended work-flow and/or setup and/or framework in order to have a dynamic web page/site but with only client-side scripting?

There is also the case that if, eg., the web-page's url is `apage.organization.domain`, then the information can be accessed from another url and rendered with the html given by `apage.organization.domain`, if such a thing can be done.

Comment: Probably too broad, but I still like the question :-)